# Ruby find date with your day except weekend

Tags: ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I want make a def get day when you input the day. We have 5 day working in week except weekend.
Ex: to day : 27/02/2018
you input: 3 -> out put: 02/03/2018
you input: 5 -> out put: 06/03/2018
you input: 7 -> out put: 08/03/2018
you input: 10 -> out put: 13/03/2018

my code:

```
require 'date'

def next_week d, c
   return d + 7 * c
end

def my_add_day day
    d = Date.today
    d = next_week d, day/5
    day = day % 5
    if (6 - d.wday) > day
        d = d + day
    else
        d = d + day + 2
    end
    return d
end
```

you can use gem https://github.com/bokmann/business_time

Comment: https://github.com/bokmann/business_time

Comment: Side note: Check out the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Ruby projects are *very* consistent in how basic code is structured - i.e. 2 space tabs, and no need for explicit `return` statements like that.

Comment: @TomLord Thank i remember note :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def add_working_days date, num
  num.times.inject(date) do |date|
    case date.wday
    when 5 then date + 3
    when 6 then date + 2
    else date + 1
    end
  end
end

main ▶ add_working_days Date.today, 3
#⇒ #<Date: 2018-03-02 ((2458180j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
main ▶ add_working_days Date.today, 5
#⇒ #<Date: 2018-03-06 ((2458184j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
main ▶ add_working_days Date.today, 7
#⇒ #<Date: 2018-03-08 ((2458186j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
main ▶ add_working_days Date.today, 10
#⇒ #<Date: 2018-03-13 ((2458191j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`business_time`](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time) gem (which allows extra features, such as defining `BusinessTime::Config.holidays`), this could be written as:

```
1.business_day.after(date)
```

Or as a more generic helper method:

```
def add_working_days(date, num)
  num.business_days.after(date)
end
```

I would advise using this library if this is a common/complex problem to solve within your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a [lazy enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) in ruby to skip all future Saturdays and Sundays and get the date of the next workday in a functional style without any conditionals.

```
def next_workday(number_of_days)
  (DateTime.now..DateTime::Infinity.new)
    .lazy
    .reject { |x| x.saturday? || x.sunday? }
    .drop(number_of_days)
    .first
end
```